# Python socket allow only one connection, but disconnect on new, not refuse

Tags: python, sockets

In python, you can define maximum number of socket connections by parameter of `listen()` function... for example:

```
serversocket = socket.socket(
socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
serversocket.bind((socket.gethostname(), 80))
serversocket.listen(1) // allow only 1 connection
```

But the problem is that when second client wants to connect, connection is being refused. And I would like to disconnect the old user and connect the new one. Could anybody help me with that?

**Probably an answer:**

*I am posting it in question as it is probable answer (I didn't have time to check it)*

```
serversocket = socket.socket(
socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
serversocket.bind((socket.gethostname(), 80))
serversocket.listen(10) // allow 10 connections, but disconnect previous later
someone_connected = 0
while 1:
    (clientsocket, address) = serversocket.accept()
    if(someone_connected) someone_connected.close()
    someone_connected = clientsocket
```

Comment: Please prove that the second client is being disconnected.

Comment: I want to desconnect it.

Comment: Have a look at the `import select` module to find out if a new connection is there.

Comment: not sure if using external modules for that is a good solution... check out mine (under question)

Comment: The select module is built in to Python; I wouldn't call it 'external'.  You'll need to call select() if you want to be notified when a new incoming TCP connection has arrived, while still doing things with your current TCP connection.

Comment: oh thank you then, I will check that out asap

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure that I fully understand you question, but I think the following example can meet your requirement.  the server can disconnect the old user and serve the new one.

the sever side:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import socket
import multiprocessing


HOST = '127.0.0.1'                
PORT = 50007      

# you can do your real staff in handler
def handler(conn, addr):
    try:
        print 'processing...'
        while 1:
            data = conn.recv(1024)
            if not data:
                break
            print data
            conn.sendall(data)
        conn.close()
        print 'processing done'
    except:
        pass

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET,socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(5)
processes = []
while True:
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print conn, addr

    [p.terminate() for p in processes] # to disconnect the old connection
    # start process newer connection and save it for next kill 
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=handler, args=(conn, addr))
    processes = [p]
    p.start()

    newest_conn = conn # this is the newest connection object, if you need it
```

For test,  the client side:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import socket
import time
import multiprocessing

HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 50007

def client():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))
    time.sleep(0.1)

    try:
        for n in range(20):
            s.send(str(n))
            data = s.recv(1024)
            print data
            time.sleep(0.5)
        s.send('')
        s.close()
    except:
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for i in range(5):
        print 'user %i connect' %i
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=client)
        p.start() # simulate a new user start connect
        time.sleep(3)
```

Try it :-)

Comment: thank you for such a great answer, i will try it as soon as I will get home

Answer (score 3):

You have a wrong assumption built into your question - the single argument to socket `listen()` is not the "number of connections", but a *`backlog`* - number of pending, but not yet accepted client connections the kernel holds for you for a while.

Your problem then seems to be that you have accepted one connection, and reading/writing to it in a loop, and not calling `accept()` again. The kernel holds the request for any new client connection for some timeout, then notifies the client that the server is not accepting it.

You want to look into `select()` functionality, as suggested in the comments.